# Error while trying to calculate power in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have this function in matlab-

```
function [c,arr2]=dist1(i,c,arr1,arr2,A,mx,point)      
    for j=i+1:mx
        if arr1(i,j)==1 & A(j)~=0
            x1=point(i,1);
            y1=point(i,2);
            x2=point(j,1);
            y2=point(j,2);
            d=((((x1-x2).^2)+((y1-y2).^2)).^(0.5));
            if d< 0.5
                arr2(c)=i;
                c=c+1;
                [c,arr2]=dist1(j,c,arr1,arr2,A,mx,point);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

When I call this function this function I get following error-

```
Integers can only be raised to positive integral powers.

Error in dist1 (line 9)
            d=((((x1-x2).^2)+((y1-y2).^2)).^(0.5));
```

This works fine if I remove power of `0.5` in the calculation of `d`.Why am I getting this error,there seems to be nothing wrong in this statement.Also I checked the values of x1,x2,y1,y2 in the preceding lines and they are

```
x1=208 y1=171 x2=207 y2=162
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is pretty explicit:

> Integers can only be raised to positive integral powers.

Your `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` variables seem to be of an integer data type (such as `uint8`, `int32`, ...). They need to be `double` (or `single`) to perform that operation. So, try

```
d = double((((x1-x2).^2)+((y1-y2).^2)).^(0.5))^0.5;
```

Note also that, since `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` are scalars, you could remove the dots:

```
d = double((((x1-x2)^2)+((y1-y2)^2))^0.5)^0.5;
```